# Compare Phone Numbers with different format

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

Phone nubmber can have different Formats , like 0XXXXXXXXXX or +91XXXXXXXXXX or XXXXXXXXXX.

In all cases , phone number is similar.

How can i compare ?

Comment: you can test it with regular expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please do this for love of god:** Handling all formats of phone numbers is as tricky and hairy as handling different data formats. It's always a sane option to use some existing "mature" library. Use [**PhoneNumberKit**](https://github.com/marmelroy/PhoneNumberKit), its one of the mature and popular libraries out there.

But if you want to live on the edge, you can try something like this -

1. Reverse the string & compare only the first 10 chars.
2. Regular Expressions would be a better solution. Have as many regular expressions as there are formats & you are good to go.
3. Please open source this library for others to benefit :)

General reading on [handling phone numbers](http://blog.barisione.org/2010-06/handling-phone-numbers/)

Comment: PhoneNumberUtils.compare is not for objective-c

Comment: But this will not work if the phone no is in +91-(XXX) XXX XXXX

Comment: @AbhishekThapliyal you are right. My answer was outdated. I updated it now.

Answer (score 0):

You could start comparing right to left using a custom character by character match code. It also works because the last few digits on phones vary more than the first few, so your code will fail fast in a unequal comparison which is what you want anyways. Keep a count of how many matches you have and if it passes a certain threshold say 10, then call the number equal. Without know more specifics this would be made to work reasonably well.

Comment: hmm .. might be this will work , as last 10 digits are important and without country code , cell numbers will be 10 digits .

Answer (score 0):

As Mentioned by srikar to reverse the string and compare 10 characters.Create the method and call it for all the three strings and after that compare them.

```
NSMutableString *reversedString = [NSMutableString string];
NSInteger charIndex = [myString length];
NSInteger count;
count=10;
while(count >= 0) {
    count--;    
    charIndex--;
    NSRange subStrRange = NSMakeRange(charIndex, 1);
    [reversedString appendString:[myString substringWithRange:subStrRange]];
}
```